# SQL calculation x between max(x) and min(x)+y

Tags: sql

How do I calculate in SQL when I need to find the entries of the values that are above the `min` value + *x*?

I tried something like

```
SELECT x
FROM table
WHERE x BETWEEN max(x) AND min(x) + 1000;
```

But this ain't working tho.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `select x from table group by x having x between max(x) and min(x) + 1000`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery:

```
select t.x
from t t
where t.x > (select min(t2.x) + 1000 from t t2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution (a bit changed to the original question):

select ..., ..., ... from ... 
where x-1000 >= (select min(x) from ...)

Thank you :)